# Can I use Rockshox tokens with my Sektor fork? (Fuel EX 5)

Tags: suspension

I would like to experiment with ramp control with tokens but I cannot find out if my fork is compatible with the regular Rockshox tokens, is it too low end??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sektor fork does not appear to have a compatible token. From the Rockshox web site https://www.sram.com/rockshox/technologies/bottomless-tokens:

- Black bottomless tokens are compatible with the following Solo Air forks: RS-1, SID, Reba, Bluto, Revelation.
- Grey bottomless tokens are compatible with the following Solo Air forks: Pike, Lyrik, Yari, Pike DJ, BoXXer.
- Dark red bottomless tokens are compatible with the following Dual Position Air forks: Pike, Lyrik, Yari.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know rockshox sektor is just a cheaper version of revalation (motion control damper, no sag indicator etching on right stanchion and no ability to add volume spacers) so you can just swap out the top cap (on the left side) and add volume spacers.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

No, the Sektor fork is too small in diameter internally.

I‘ve tried but the tokens‘ diameter is too wide to fit inside the bore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Did you try cutting or trimming the tokens?  Use [edit] to enlarge your initial answer.  I've made some minor changes to increase the relevance to the original question, but feel free to correct anything that may be wrong or misleading.