# Is there any way i can add progressiveness to my suspension, even though it is not compatible with standard tokens?

Tags: fork, suspension

Off the back of my  [last question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51800/can-i-use-rockshox-tokens-with-my-sektor-fork-fuel-ex-5/51805#51805), is there any way i could be able to add some progressiveness to my suspension, maybe i could retrofit tokens or something of the like.

Thanks.

Comment: Your last question got an answer showing its not compatible with tokens.  Best to stop wasting money on a lower end fork and save up to replace it with something better.

Comment: All you need is something to take up some of the air volume inside the fork. No idea what an advisable way to this is though.

Comment: If you take the fork apart you could possibly find space to put some sort of improvised token. Reassemble, see if it works. This is obviously a lot of work. You may be better off looking for a compatible higher end used fork in good condition.

Comment: @Criggie what fork would you recommend to replace it with??

Comment: @BenPoulter a rigid fork :-P

Answer (score 1):

As @alex commented you need something that takes up some air volume. 
Around 10 years ago in the downhill racing scene this was also needed by some heavy riders. The solution was to pour some fork oil into the air chamber to make it take space there. The oil will also eventually get into the negative air chamber when the fork is compressed to the groove on the inside, so the characteristics of the fork will change during a single descent.

The only other solution that comes to my mind (actually it is a bodge) is to use Formula's [Neopos](https://www.rideformula.com/technologies/neopos/) volume spacers, and just squeeze them into the fork (its air chamber). Those are foam-based and it might work.

But I think you are better off buying a fork capable of taking proper volume spacers.